# How to submit form onclick like google's autosuggest with jqueryui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Looks like using categories with jqueryui made things a little bit complicated. I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var self = this,
                currentCategory = "";
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                self._renderItem( ul, item );
            });
        },

      select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("input#autocomplete_text").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#autocomplete_form").submit();
      }
    });
    $( "#autocomplete_text" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/suggestions'); ?>",
                data: { term: $("#autocomplete_text").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

With that form:

```
                    <form id="autocomplete_form" name="input" action="autocomplete/redirect" method="post">
                        <input size="38" type="text" id="autocomplete_text" name="autocomplete_text" value="İlan kodu, kategori, ilan veya emlakçı ara" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="0" />
                        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value=" EMLAK ARA " />
                    </form>
```

My [example](http://www.bedavaemlaksitesi.com/mersinemlakrehberi210/autocomplete/index)

What i want to do is, submit form after clicking on an item in the suggestions list.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your example works for me just can't post as it's a PHP error. What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: @dannix Did you read the title of questino ? What i want to do is, submit form after clicking on an item in the suggestions list.

Comment: I did yes but didn't understand you want to submit after selecting a suggestion.

Comment: @dannix i have updated the question for clarify. sorry.

Comment: No problem :-) I've posted my answer. Can't explain why your way didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the select: function from the ui.autocomplete init function and move it to the catcomplete function

Embedded PHP and reliance on your server responding with categories makes editing for us outside your web domain a hassle.

Working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hKk7D/2/) less the ajax stuff.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category +   "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
$( "#autocomplete_text" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
    $("#autocomplete_form").submit();
  },
    source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/suggestions'); ?>",
            data: { term: $("#autocomplete_text").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should check your php file first.. You are getting Undefined variable: link.. which means that the $link variable is not set or  an array from your ajax is not passing thru.

Comment: i have updated my question. Submitting form is not a problem, problem is submitting button after selecting an item. Like "onselect"

Comment: The only solution i see is that you make  a click event and settind a value .For that i suggest your wrap your categories with a <span>. 
 
Then say

$('<span>').click(function(){var item=$(this).html(); });

after that just send the var item as your search term when the submit button is clicked.